# How can I refresh a user's session using JWT token

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, owin, jwt

I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm trying to implement a mechanism for keeping active users logged in as long as they're active.

I have a token endpoint that issues a JWT token to a user

```
{  
      "access_token": "base64encodedandsignedstring",
      "token_type": "bearer",
      "expires_in": 299,
      "refresh_token": "f87ae3bee04b4ca39af6f22a198274df",
      "as:client_id": "mysite",
      "userName": "me@email.com",
      ".issued": "Wed, 19 Apr 2017 20:15:58 GMT",
      ".expires": "Wed, 19 Apr 2017 20:20:58 GMT"
}
```

And another call that takes the refresh_token and uses it to generate a new access token.  From the Api standpoint this should enable me to pass in the refresh_token and generate a new JWT with a new expires date.

I'm not 100% sure on how to wire up the Angular side to support this, my login function:

```
var _login = function (LoginData) {

    var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + LoginData.UserName + "&password=" + LoginData.Password + "&client_id=4TierWeb";

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post(serviceBase + 'authToken', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).then(function (response) {

        localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.data.access_token, userName: LoginData.userName, refreshToken: response.data.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });

        _authentication.isAuth = true;
        _authentication.userName = LoginData.UserName;

        deferred.resolve(response);

    }, function (err, status) {
        _logOut();
        deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;

};
```

My refresh function:

```
var _refreshToken = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');

    if (authData) {

        if (authData.useRefreshTokens) {

            var data = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + authData.refreshToken + "&client_id=4TierWeb";

            localStorageService.remove('authorizationData');

            $http.post(serviceBase + 'authToken', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).then(function (response) {

                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.data.access_token, userName: response.data.userName, refreshToken: response.data.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });
               // response.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.token;
                deferred.resolve(response);

            }, function (err, status) {
                _logOut();
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        }
    }

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And my interceptor:

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {
        request: function (config) {

            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
            if (authData) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                    }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (error) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    };
    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

My interceptor works great without the refresh mechanism in place as above, but when I add the refresh mechanism:

```
   authService.RefreshToken();
   config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
```

I'm able to pull down a new JWT but the next line doesn't seem to be working correctly anymore, I'm getting 401 on my landing page and there is no bearer token in the payload, what am I missing here?

Updated Interceptor:

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService',['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', '$injector', function($q, $location, localStorageService, $injector) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {

                config.headers = config.headers || {};

                var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
                if (authData) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                //var promise = $q.reject(rejection);

                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    var authService = $injector.get('authService');
                    // refresh the token
                    authService.refreshToken().then(function() {
                        // retry the request
                        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                        return $http(rejection.config);
                    });
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: When are you calling `authService.RefreshToken();`? You should use the refresh token to request a new access token only when your access token is expired or you receive from server an error code stating that is expired, thus refreshing and retrying. Please add also the logic for refreshToken() function.

Comment: Copy paste fail, the refresh function is in there.  I think I can also use the refresh token to update the expiration date upon user request no?  Is there a better way to do it? Eventually in v2.0 of this code I'm going to only send the refresh token every 30 min of an hour session or so.

Comment: What do you need the access_token for? Do you use it as an authentication token for your AngularJS to backed calls? Or the backend uses it for calling some other services on behalf of the user?

Comment: The access token is a JWT Bearer token, it contains for example roles.  I attach a refresh token Id to it that I can then use to generate a new JWT & refresh token (by changing my payload to the auth endpoint) to it by calling the refresh token, which updates the .expires field in my payload.  I'm more or less following http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ for the API implementation.  I think my next step is to implement angular-jwt > https://auth0.com/blog/handling-jwts-on-angular-is-finally-easier/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the refresh_token request to complete obtaining a new access token and then use the response to issue a new request.

Like: `authService.refreshToken().then(doRequest())`

Lets suppose that you have 2 functions inside `authService`:

`function getAccessToken() { ...get access token like in login()... }` - returning Promise

`function refreshToken() { ...existing logic... }` - returning Promise

Let us say that you will use [`jwt_decode(jwt)`](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) to decode the JWT token.

I think you can go two ways with your implementation:

**1st way:** get the token and immediately subscribe in order to refresh when expired

```
function getAccessToken() {
  ...
  return $http(...)
    .then(function(response) {
       // ...correct credentials logic...

       if(authService.refreshTimeout) {
         $window.clearTimeout(authService.refreshTimeout);
       }

       // decode JWT token
       const access_token_jwt_data = jwt_decode(response.data.access_token);

       // myOffset is an offset you choose so you can refresh the token before expiry
       const expirationDate = new Date(access_token_jwt_data * 1000 - myOffset);

       // refresh the token when expired
       authService.refreshTimeout = $window.setTimeout(function() {
         authService.refreshToken();
       });

       return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // ...invalid credentials logic...
      return $q.reject(error);
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** You can use `window` instead of `$window`. I don't think that you actually need a new digest cycle at that moment. A new digest will be launched when $http request completes successfully or not.

**NOTE:** This means that you need to take care also of the case when you reload the page. Thus re-enabling the refresh timeout. So you can reuse the logic within `getAccessToken()` for subscribing to expiry date but this time you get the token from the `localStorage`. This means that you can refactor this logic into a new function called something like `function subscribeToTokenExpiry(accessToken)`. So you can call this function in your `authService` constructor if there is an access token in your localStorage.

**2nd way:** refresh the token in your HTTP interceptor after receiving an error code from server.

You can refresh your token if your interceptor receives an error that match a token expiry case. This depends strongly on your back-end implementation so you may receive HTTP 401 or 400 or anything else and some custom error message or code. So you need to check with your back-end. Also check if they are consistent in returning the HTTP statuses and error codes. Some implementation details might change over time and framework developers might advice users to not rely on that specific implementation because is only for internal use. In that case you can leave only the HTTP status and omit the code, as you will have better chances of having the same in the future. But ask your back-end or the ones that created the framework.

**NOTE:** regarding Spring OAuth2 back-end implementation, find the details at the end of this answer.

Getting back to your code, your interceptor should look like:

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService',
    ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', 'authService', '$injector',
    function ($q, $location, localStorageService, authService, $injector) {
    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {
        request: function (config) {

            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
            if (authData) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            let promise = $q.reject(response);

            if (response.status === 401
                && response.data 
                && response.data.error === 'invalid_token') {

                // refresh the token
                promise = authService.refreshToken().then(function () {
                    // retry the request
                    const $http = $injector.get('$http');
                    return $http(response.config);
                });
            }

            return promise.catch(function () {
                $location.path('/login');
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        }
    };
    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

**Spring Security OAuth2 back-end related:**

I add this section for those curious about Spring Authorization Server implementation as Spring is a very popular framework in the Java world.

**1) Expiry date**

Regarding the expiry date, this is expressed in **seconds**. You will find the "exp" key inside your access_token and refresh_token after you JWT decode the string.

This is in seconds because you add the [`JwtAccessTokenConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.java) which uses [`DefaultAccessTokenConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultAccessTokenConverter.java) that does:

```
if (token.getExpiration() != null) {
  response.put(EXP, token.getExpiration().getTime() / 1000);
}
```

[`JwtAccessTokenConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.java) is added when the Authorization Server is being configured:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    // ...
    endpoints.accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter)
    // ...
  }
}
```

**2) Access token expired response**

You might need to handle one or both of `HTTP 400` and `HTTP 401` statuses and rely on `{ "error": "invalid_token" }`. But this depends strongly on how the back-end was implemented using Spring.

See the explanations bellow:

Regarding, the resource server configuration (the one to which we send the request to in order to get the resource we want), the flow is as follows:

1. [`OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java) servlet filter to get access token from request
2. [`OAuth2AuthenticationManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java) to parse token string
3. [`DefaultTokenServices`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java) to obtain the access token object.
4. `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` try catch will delegate the exceptions to [`OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/error/OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.java) which creates the response for the exception.

`DefaultTokenServices` is a `ResourceServerTokenServices` implementation.
There are two possible such implementations, one is this `DefaultTokenServices` and the other is [`RemoteTokenServices`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.java).

If we use `DefaultTokenServices` then the token will be checked on the resource server. This means that the resource server has knowledge of the key that signed the token in order to check the token validity. This approach means distributing the key to all parties that want such behavior.

If we use `RemoteTokenServices` then the token will be checked against `/oauth/check_token` endpoint handled by [`CheckTokenEndpoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.java).

On expiry `CheckTokenEndpoint` will create an [`InvalidTokenException`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/exceptions/InvalidTokenException.java) with HTTP 400, that will converted by [`OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Serializer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/exceptions/OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Serializer.java) into `HTTP 400` with data `{ "error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Token has expired" }`.

On the other hand `DefaultTokenServices` will create also a `InvalidTokenException` exception but with other message and without overriding the HTTP status thus being HTTP 401 in the end. So this will become `HTTP 401` with data `{ "error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Access token expired: myTokenValue" }`.

Again this, `HTTP 400` or `HTTP 401`, happens because `InvalidTokenException` is thrown in both cases `DefaultTokenServices` throws without overriding `getHttpErrorCode()` which is `401` but `CheckTokenEndpoint` overrides it with `400`.

**Note:** I added a [Github Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1043) in order to check if this behavior, 400 vs 401, is correct.

Comment: My goal is to never issue a 401 unless my user has gone inactive (ex. gone to lunch).  By issuing refresh_token requests a new JWT is generated with a new exp date & the refresh_token exp date is updated.  I believe I can use this mechanism to keep an active user logged in indefinitely by issuing a new refresh_token, I don't think I can use an idling mechanism because OWIN (I'm using .NET) will 401 expired JWTs & refresh_tokens.  I think your way is for updating the access token when that expires by issuing a long living refresh token.  If I issue a refresh token for 3 hours, they'd just get

Comment: a new access token when they got back instead of getting booted.  I wonder if I'm approaching this problem from the wrong angle as folks tend to use refresh_tokens for updating access permissions.  Is there a better way for me to keep a user logged in using JWT based off of activity?  Either way I'll probably keep the refresh_token so folks at least don't have to relog to update their perms.

Comment: After doing some more research, maybe I'll issue a 12 hour refresh_token, use the refresh_token mechanism as intended (by everyone but me) to refresh the access token when the access token expires and then on the client side I'll look for idle users using something like ng-idle and remove their localstorage when they haven't done anything for an hour or so.

Comment: @RandomUs1r receiving HTTP 401 is not necessarily a one-to-one relationship with the fact the the user is not logged on a client app. Usually responses have HTTP statuses but might as well have some information like error codes which provide additional semantics. In the code I provided above, there is the angular http interceptor that will catch HTTP 401.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I provided two solutions: the first is to set an interval for refreshing a token and also set this interval on app startup if there is a access token in local storage, the second one is by using the http interceptor to handle HTTP 401 with a specific error code, refresh the token and retry the original request thus passing the new access token. In both cases the angular http interceptor, if the refresh token is not valid, will lend you the login page and the user will be considered as unauthenticated.

Comment: @RandomUs1r if you want to have a user being logged out after 1h of inactivity, this is equivalent to have an access token with an expiration less than 1h (say 30min) and a refresh token with an expiration of 1h. If the refresh token expires then you cannot get an access token, thus not being able to authenticate without logging in.

Comment: I understand, thank you for explaining it, I grabbed your second example, modified it a bit and updated op.  I've still got an issue where I get the 401, then do a 200 auth with the refresh token id, however I'm getting kicked back to login after that.  Console shows Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request.".  It seems that I'm hitting the catch portion of the code instead of the interceptor request, any ideas?

Comment: you can check if you've got your new access token set (on local storage) and if the interceptor request method is adding the Bearer header with the value of the newly obtained access token.

Comment: Looks like I'm not hitting return $http(response.config); I get a 200 on the refresh token, the storage gets updated (which is awesome).  I haven't been able to look at it for a few days, hoping to fix it soon!

Comment: Update: my call chain now looks like 401 > 200 refresh > 200 on the original function.  I've posted v2 of my updated interceptor.  Last question:  it seems that when i do return $http(rejection.config) the page is not updated, the subsequent call returns 200 with the data + it's updated jwt, is this something I need to handle on the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) at a couple of occasions without any problems.
You can set it up to refresh the token silently and only throw an error (and navigate to the login screen) if the refresh fails. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is it secure to use a refresh token in an Angular application ? I'am not sure...
The OIDC implicit flow (which is the flow used for SPA or mobile apps), there is no refresh token involved.